# Why codes of EMOJI symbols are different in browser and Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, emoji

I saved EMOJI symbol from web-application to Oracle Database. In html this symbol is coded by &#128514.
Ie if I write

```
<html>&#128514</html>
```

, I will see it in Browser.
But in DB the query

```
select ascii(sym) from ..
```

returns value 4036991106.
The question is why these codes are different (128514 and 4036991106), and how to convert one to another?
The Query

```
select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'
```

returns value 'AL32UTF8'.
The query

```
select sym...
```

Returns '', this is the symbol I have saved.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation: [ASCII](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions014.htm#SQLRF00604)

> `ASCII` returns the decimal representation in the database character set
>   of the first character of char.

- 4036991106 is the decimal number in UTF-8 (i.e. AL32UTF8)
- 128514 is the decimal number in UTF-32BE

See also [Face with Tears of Joy U+1F602](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F602/)

Conversion is not so trivial, you can use this block.

```
DECLARE
    codepoint INTEGER := 128514;

    sg1 CHAR(2);
    sg2 CHAR(2);
    sg3 CHAR(2);
    sg4 CHAR(2);

    res VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN   

    --128 = x80 = 10000000 -> 10xxxxxx
    --192 = xC0 = 11000000 -> 110xxxxx
    --224 = eE0 = 11100000 -> 1110xxxx
    --240 = xF0 = 11110000 -> 11110xxx

    IF codepoint <= 127 THEN        
        res := LPAD(TO_CHAR(codepoint, 'fmXX'), 2, '0');
    ELSIF codepoint <= 2047 THEN
        sg1 := TO_CHAR(192 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**6), 'fmXX');
        sg2 := TO_CHAR(128 + codepoint MOD 2**6, 'fmXX');
        res := LPAD(sg1, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg2, 2, '0');
    ELSIF codepoint <= 65535 THEN
        sg1 := TO_CHAR(224 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**12), 'fmXX');        
        sg2 := TO_CHAR(128 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**6) MOD 2**6, 'fmXX');
        sg3 := TO_CHAR(128 + codepoint MOD 2**6, 'fmXX');
        res := LPAD(sg1, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg2, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg3, 2, '0');
    ELSE
        sg1 := TO_CHAR(240 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**18), 'fmXX');        
        sg2 := TO_CHAR(128 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**12) MOD 2**12, 'fmXX');
        sg3 := TO_CHAR(128 + TRUNC(codepoint / 2**6) MOD 2**6, 'fmXX');
        sg4 := TO_CHAR(codepoint MOD 2**6 + 128, 'fmXX');
        res := LPAD(sg1, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg2, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg3, 2, '0')||LPAD(sg4, 2, '0');
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Hex:'||res );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Decimal: '||TO_NUMBER(res, 'XXXXXXXX') );

END;
```

Result:

```
Hex: F09F9882
Decimal: 4036991106
```

For conversion in the other direction you can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNICODECHAR(uchar VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS

    utf16 VARCHAR2(10) := ASCIISTR(uchar);
    sg1 VARCHAR2(4);
    sg2 VARCHAR2(4);
    codepoint INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF REGEXP_LIKE(utf16, '^\\') THEN
        IF LENGTH(utf16) = 5 THEN
            RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE(utf16, '^\\');
        ELSE
            sg1 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(utf16, '[[:xdigit:]]{4}');
            sg2 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(utf16, '[[:xdigit:]]{4}', 5);
            codepoint := 2**10 * (TO_NUMBER(sg1, 'XXXX') - TO_NUMBER('D800', 'XXXX')) + TO_NUMBER(sg2, 'XXXX') - TO_NUMBER('DC00', 'XXXX') + 2**16;
            RETURN TO_CHAR(codepoint, 'fmXXXXXX');
        END IF; 
    ELSE
        RETURN TO_CHAR(ASCII(uchar), 'fmXX');
    END IF;

END UNICODECHAR;
```

Then run

```
select TO_NUMBER(UNICODECHAR(sym), 'XXXXXXXX') from ..
```